# MySQL: have internal query reference external column on same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this

```
id | startTime           | endTime
1  | 2012-11-07 12:33:23 | 2012-11-07 12:44:44
3  | 2012-11-07 12:45:55 | 2012-11-07 12:48:43
9  | 2012-11-07 12:47:23 | 2012-11-07 13:00:00
13 | 2012-11-08 12:32:22 | 2012-11-08 13:00:00
```

How can I write a query that returns me

```
id | CountNumIDsBeforeThisIDOnSameDay | CountNumIDsThatEndedBeforeThisIDOnSameDay
1  | 0                                | 0
3  | 1                                | 1
9  | 2                                | 1
13 | 0                                | 0
```

**Other assumptions**

id may not be in running number

I am not sure how to phrase what I am thinking in an easy manner. But basically, I know I can get the counts easily if I can reference the current row ID in my sub-query. I was also thinking of using `LEFT OUTER JOINS` but I am not sure if I am complicating things myself.

Comment: Could you provide samples of data with desired results?

Comment: yeah I just did! figured that will help people understand my question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05347f/10)

```
select id,
(select count(*) from T 
    where DATE(startTime)=DATE(T1.startTime)
          AND 
          StartTime<T1.StartTime  
) as 
CountNumIDsBeforeThisIDOnSameDay,

(select count(*) from T 
    where DATE(startTime)=DATE(T1.startTime)
          AND 
          EndTime<T1.StartTime  
) as 
CountNumIDsThatEndedBeforeThisIDOnSameDay


from T as T1
Order by StartTime
```

Comment: thanks so much @valex. Just one more thing, can I show the difference between the Counts as well in a fourth column? I tried to add `,( CountNumIDsBeforeThisIDOnSameDay - CountNumIDsThatEndedBeforeThisIDOnSameDay)` but that didnt work.